# Prevent app crash from loading many assets

Tags: java, android, kotlin, memory

I have an android app with many resource images , actually they are four folders each one with nearly from 10 to 14 photos , i use this method to load them inside their activities

```
// for ball activity

fun getImages(): ArrayList<Drawable> {

    var items = ArrayList<Drawable>()

    try {

        var ims = MyApplication.appContext.assets.list("images/ball")!!

        for (i in 0..ims.size - 1) {

            val res = MyApplication.appContext.assets.open("images/ball/" + ims[i])

            val d1 = Drawable.createFromStream(res, null)

            items.add(d1)

            res.close()
        }

        return items

    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        return items
    }
}
```

the problem is after i open all the activities in a small period of time i get the memory space crash here

```
val d1 = Drawable.createFromStream(res, null)
```

So i think of 2 ways to handle that

1- i need to make their array of images global and load all of them when opening the app

2- i need to make their array of images global and load every opened activity to set it's array to the global 1 as not to load a again

my question is what is the best from the above ways ? or is there any better 1 , BTW i added this in manifest

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: Any help please on what i should do ?

Comment: Use an image library like Picasso or Glide, which can manage loading and unloading as images scroll on and off the screen. Then you aren't holding images in memory when they aren't even visible.

Comment: @Tenfour04 images are in local assets folder ? Glide / Picasso would be useful for local ?

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you it helps improving it after i used `Glide` many thanks you can add as answer and will accept it

Comment: @Tenfour04 Can you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039443/hide-status-bar-when-sharing-text-android , thanks in advance .